# Flask - How to query a one-to-many relationship to display on webpage

Tags: python, flask, foreign-keys

I have two tables: **FundingSource()** and **AllocationSummary()**. I'm using a foreign key since there's a one to many relationship between the two tables - a funding source can have many allocations, but an allocation can only have one funding source.

These are my two tables:

```
class FundingSource(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    complete = db.Column(db.String(10), default=False, nullable=False)
    department = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    agency = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    funding_source = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    bill = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    allocations = db.relationship('AllocationSummary', backref='allocation', lazy=True) 


class AllocationSummary(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    state = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    eligible_applicant = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    recipient = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    amount = db.Column(db.Float(), nullable=False)
    funding_source_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('funding_source.id'), nullable=False)
```

I have a webpage Allocation Summary with a `<table>` as so: [image: Web Page]

My problem is, **how do I query the FundingSource table to get the complete, agency, funding_source, bill attributes AND query the AllocationSummary table to get the state, eligible_applicant, recipient, amount attributes using my foreign key?**

In essence, I need to join the two tables using the id and foreign key to then populate my Allocation Summary table on the webpage.

So, the first 5 columns need to be read in from FundingSource and the last 4 columns need to he read in from AllocationSummary.

Here is my .py file:

```
@main.route("/")
@main.route("/guidance_master")
def g_master():
    f_sources = FundingSource.query.all()
    return render_template('guidance_master.html', title='Guidance Master', fsources=f_sources)

@main.route("/allocationSummary")
def alloc_summ():
    all_data2 = AllocationSummary.query.filter(AllocationSummary.funding_source_id == FundingSource.id).all()
    return render_template('allocationSummary.html', title='Allocation Summary', allocs=all_data2)
```

Here is my HTML file:

```
                    ....
                    <tbody>

                    {% for row in allocs%}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.complete }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.agency }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.funding_source }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.bill }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.state }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.eligible_applicant }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.recipient }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.amount }}</td>
                    </tr>

                    {% endfor %}

                    </tbody>
                    ....
```

I just can't seem to find a way to query using attributes from 2 different tables at once to display in my table. These are the 2 queries I have tried:

```
all_data2 = AllocationSummary.query.filter(AllocationSummary.funding_source_id == FundingSource.id).all()

all_data2 = db.session.query(FundingSource, AllocationSummary).join(AllocationSummary)\
         .filter(AllocationSummary.funding_source_id == FundingSource.id)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a `backref` in the `db.relationship` in the `FundingSource` but instead of calling it `allocation` i would call it `foundingsource` because this will be the member on the `Allocation`. With that member you can access the Data of the associate `FoundingSource` like this:

```
 ....
                    <tbody>

                    {% for row in allocs%}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.foundingsource.complete }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.foundingsource.agency }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.foundingsource.funding_source }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.foundingsource.bill }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.state }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.eligible_applicant }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.recipient }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row.amount }}</td>
                    </tr>

                    {% endfor %}

                    </tbody>
                    ....
```

This would be the definition of the relationship:

```
    allocations = db.relationship('AllocationSummary', backref='foundingsource', lazy=True)
```

Because the `backref` is the name of the Member which will be added to the corresponding class of the relationship.

[One To Many SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many)

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for this answer. How would I go about querying in my .py file above though? TIA!

Comment: You don't need to change your query. It's all in there

Comment: I wanted to read in the complete, agency, funding_source, bill attributes from my FundingSource table and get the remainder 4 columns from the AllocationSummary table. When I tried your answer, none of my rows from FundingSource are getting read in to populate those first 5 columns?

Comment: how do you query the database?

Comment: I'm joining the two tables as so: all_data2 = AllocationSummary.query.join(FundingSource).filter(AllocationSummary.funding_source_id == FundingSource.id).all()

Comment: I want to be able to read in my FundingSource table rows and join my AllocationSummary table rows to it and get the necessary column values show in the picture in my post. The only thing is, I don't have the same # of rows when joining the two tables, so some of the row values will be blank for the Allocation Summary columns  (the last 4 columns in the picture)

Comment: for the query why do you do the `AllocationSummary.founding_source_id == FundingSource.id).all()`